# Unable to make a release build when using react-native-paytm

Tags: react-native, paytm

I am using [react-native-paytm](https://github.com/elanic-tech/react-native-paytm), and getting this issue when trying to make build using ./gradlew assembleRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-paytm:verifyReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

How can I fix it?